# how to add items to resource file (resx) on run time?

Tags: asp.net

i have some global resource files that store my dictionary for app.
when a key is not in the resource file i return the key.

```
public Object MyGetGlobalResourceObject(string classKey, string resourceKey)
    {
        try
        {
            if (GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey) == null)
            {
                return resourceKey;
            }
            else
                return GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey);

        }
        catch (MissingManifestResourceException ex)
        {
             return classKey + "-" + resourceKey + " " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

i want to add the resourceKey to the classKey file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ResXResourceReader class, here is an example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Editing_a_ResourceFile.aspx?msg=3406807